# move sprite on path in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to move a sprite on this path using cocos2d.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8436ca404e.jpg
(stackoverflow does not allow new users to post image!)

Any help would me much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a chance to find the way to move sprites along the pre-defined path?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link for the actions using cocos2d. You could create an action with the positions and run the action when you want.

[Actions](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:actions)

There are multiple actions for changing a sprites postion.

position

```
  CCMoveBy
  CCMoveTo
  CCJumpBy
  CCJumpTo
  CCBezierBy
  CCBezierTo
  CCPlace
```

You will find the links there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cardinalspline for moving sprite on set of points. it allows more then 3 points

Here is an example:

```
PointArray *pointarray=PointArray::create(5);
pointarray->addControlPoint(Vec2(50, 50));
pointarray->addControlPoint(Vec2(560, 50));
pointarray->addControlPoint(Vec2(255, 353));
pointarray->addControlPoint(Vec2(543, 534));
pointarray->addControlPoint(Vec2(354, 12));

sprite->runaction(CardinalSplineTo::create(3, pointarray, .5));
```